# Sitecore 8 error SPEAK error after upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-speak-ui

I just did a test upgrade on a Sitecore 7.5 site. The upgrade process went off without a hitch. I navigated to /sitecore and saw the fancy new 8 login screen. I entered my admin creds and was then presented with a .net error:

> Could not get pipeline: speak.client.initialize.layout (domain: )

```
Line 17: </head>
Line 18: <body class="sc @bodyClass">
Line 19:   @Html.Sitecore().InitializeSpeakLayout()
Line 20:   <div class="sc-list">
Line 21:     @this.Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("Page.Internal.BeforeGrid")
```

The error is on Line 19

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Check that `\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Speak.config` includes the `speak.client.initialize.layout` section. If not, something went a bit wrong with the upgrade. You could copy across the configs from a clean Sitecore 8 zip file just to be sure there is not something else missed out.

Comment: Solution from jammykam helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you compared the DLLs in your bin directory to the zip of the web root from dev.sitecore.net? Are you missing any of the SPEAK DLLs?

These are the SPEAK DLL's i have in my Sitecore 8 site. Also as Kam said check your call all the SPEAK config files. Again compare against the zip of the web root you can get from dev.sitecore.net

[image: SPEAK DLLs]

Comment: DLLs where missing. There's no instructions to move DLLs, I think the package was suppose to install these, but it didn't. hmmm. Anyway, I added them and things are running now. Thanks.